Was Abigail, in part, the inspiration for Proverbs 31:10?



Berean Strong's Lexicon chayil: strength, valor, army, wealth, capability



:10 Who can find a virtuous wife? For her worth [is] far above rubies. [Pro 31:10 NKJV]
(Literally a wife of valor, in the sense of all forms of excellence)
Was Lemuel's mother thinking of this story?

18 Then Avigayil made haste, and took two hundred loaves, and two bottles of wine, and five sheep ready dressed, and five measures of parched grain, and one hundred clusters of raisins, and two hundred cakes of figs, and laid them on donkeys. 19 She said to her young men, Go on before me; behold, I come after you. But she didn't tell her husband, Naval. 20 It was so, as she rode on her donkey, and came down by the covert of the mountain, that behold, David and his men came down toward her; and she met them. ... 23 When Avigayil saw David, she hurried, and alighted from her donkey, and fell before David on her face, and bowed herself to the ground. 24 She fell at his feet, and said, On me, my lord, on me be the iniquity; and please let your handmaid speak in your ears. Hear the words of your handmaid. [1Sa 25:18-20, 23-24 HNV]

Was Abigail in part the inspiration for Proverbs 31? Don't get me wrong, there are many a great women in Bible, and in our world today. Yet was the writer of this Chapter thinking of her, knowing the history of King David and Abigail and David's influence on Soloman and the book Proverbs? Pro 4:3-9

10 Who can find a worthy woman? For her price is far above rubies. 11 The heart of her husband trusts in her. He shall have no lack of gain. 12 She does him good, and not harm, All the days of her life. 13 She seeks wool and flax, And works eagerly with her hands. 14 She is like the merchant ships. She brings her bread from afar. 15 She rises also while it is yet night, Gives food to her household, And portions for her servant girls. 16 She considers a field, and buys it. With the fruit of her hands, she plants a vineyard. 17 She girds her loins with strength, And makes her arms strong. 18 She perceives that her merchandise is profitable. Her lamp doesn't go out by night. 19 She lays her hands to the distaff, And her hands hold the spindle. 20 She opens her arms to the poor; Yes, she extends her hands to the needy. 21 She is not afraid of the snow for her household; For all her household are clothed with scarlet. 22 She makes for herself carpets of tapestry. Her clothing is fine linen and purple. 23 Her husband is respected in the gates, When he sits among the Zakenim of the land. 24 She makes linen garments and sells them, And delivers sashes to the merchant. 25 Strength and dignity are her clothing. She laughs at the time to come. 26 She opens her mouth with wisdom. Faithful instruction is on her tongue. 27 She looks well to the ways of her household, And doesn't eat the bread of idleness. 28 Her children rise up and call her blessed. Her husband also praises her: 29 "Many women do noble things, But you excel them all." 30 Charm is deceitful, and beauty is vain; But a woman who fears the LORD, she shall be praised. 31 Give her of the fruit of her hands! Let her works praise her in the gates! [Pro 31:10-31 HNV]


We are not told so we do not know.

As much as I agree that Abigail ranks among the greatest women of the Bible, the idea that she is the inspiration of Prov. 31 has no strong basis. Objections include:

The proverb is introduced as part of "the words of Lemuel, king of Massa, the instruction his mother taught him." Abigail was one of the early wives of King David, so it's a stretch to think that Lemuel's mother - whoever  she was - taught him about Abigail as the ideal wife.

Abigail herself does not fit the description. Before she met David she was the wife of a wealthy herder, not a city dweller. After she met David she continued to live a nomadic life. Only much later did she dwell in a city - namely Hebron. Her activities there are not described and she fades from the narrative before David to Jerusalem. Theses things considered, it is unlikely that she would come to mind when Lemuel's mothers described the idea wife in these terms:



With the fruit of her hands, she plants a vineyard. 17 She girds her
loins with strength, And makes her arms strong. 18 She perceives that
her merchandise is profitable. Her lamp doesn't go out by night. 19
She lays her hands to the distaff, And her hands hold the spindle. 20
She opens her arms to the poor; Yes, she extends her hands to the
needy. 21 She is not afraid of the snow for her household; For all her
household are clothed with scarlet. 22 She makes for herself carpets
of tapestry. Her clothing is fine linen and purple. 23 Her husband is
respected in the gates.

Conclusion: The above description does not fit wit Abigail as she is described in the biblical narrative. It is possible that she did some of them after David moved to Hebron and Jerusalem. However, even then, she was not David's primary wife. Maacah and Bathsheba are better candidates, but even the idea that this would be a wife of King David is speculation. Given that Abigail fades from the picture prior to David's move to Jerusalem, the hypothesis does not have a strong basis.
